# TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined when adding google-tag-manager to reactjs site

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, react-proptypes, react-static

My site is build on `react-static`,a framework based on `reactjs`.

I follow the google [guide](https://github.com/holidaycheck/react-google-tag-manager#readme) for adding the `react-google-tag-manager` to the project.

When i refresh page i get the following error on the browser, for GoogleTagManager module:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

at

```
GoogleTagManager.propTypes = {
     gtmId: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
```

It seams React as no long the `Proptypes` property.

Enverioment:

- "react": "16.8.4",
- "react-google-tag-manager": "2.2.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`prop-types` is its own package these days](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). It got moved to a separate package in v15.5.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class GoogleTagManager extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    gtmId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    // ...
  };

  // ...
}
```